# variable in module pattern not assigned issue

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

I am new to javascript and  module pattern.
So I am trying to write the following small library

```
(function(window, $){
    'use strict';


    function myLibrary(){
        var myLib = {};
        var options= {};
        var map;

        //_options =  {'map':ol.map, 'geojson': testdata}
        myLib.init = function init(_options){
            options = _options;

            map = _options.map;
            console.log("Initializing  ...");
            console.log("map : "+ map);
            console.log("options : "+ options);
        }

        myLib.map = map;
        myLib.options = options;

        return myLib;
    }

    if(typeof (window.testLib) === 'undefined'){
        window.testLib = myLibrary();
    }

})(window, $);
```

I first call init function with the following parameters :

```
testLib.init( {'map':ol.map, 'geojson': testdata})
```

The problem come when I try to access the map and the option

```
 testLib.map   // return undefined instead of the map object
 testLib.options   // reutrn {}  instead of  {'map':ol.map, 'geojson': testdata}
```

I made the assignement in init but it doesnt seems to work.  the assignment made in init() for map and options seems to be local to the init()

How can I make the assignment  the the  map and options that I declare with var ??

Thanks for help

EDIT :  correct sentence ,  should read : "I first call init function with the following parameters :"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assignment here doesn't do what you think.

```
myLib.map = map;
myLib.options = options;
```

At the time that first runs `init()` has not yet happened, so `map` is `undefined` and `options` is `{}`. Then later `init()` runs and changes your internal variables, but that doesn't update the value of `myLib.map` at all, because it separate variable.

This pattern doesn't work well with properties, instead you want functions that can access that scope. For instance:

```
myLib.getMap = function() { return map; };
```

With that `testLib.getMap()` should fetch and return that internal variable. In this patterns the functions act as gatekeepers to your data.

---

Alternatively, if your target environment supports it you can use property getters.

```
var myLib = {
  get map() { return map };
}
```

And then this will work as you expect, because it executes a function under the hood.

```
testLib.map; // trigger property getter function.
```

But this is not universally supported, and legacy javascript engines do not have support.

Comment: the first call to init  function is with the parameter shown in the call,  I dont call it with empty parameters.

Comment: I read your response multiple time ,  and just  realize that declaring a variable with  'var'  create a private variable  within the scope of the function.

Comment: I cannot use  the property getters  since I am using the  self invoking and a function.  the getters is used only in object litteral.

Answer (score 0):

The time `testLib.map` is set `map` is undefined so that gets returned when you access `testLib.map`, same for options the value remains the first value you assigned, i.e. `{}`.

To solve your issue on the `init` method manipulate directly the `myLib` object like so

```
(function(window, $){
    'use strict';

    function myLibrary(){
        var myLib = {};
        var options= {};
        var map;

        //_options =  {'map':ol.map, 'geojson': testdata}
        myLib.init = function init(_options){
            options = _options;
            map = _options.map;

            // ADD THESE TWO LINES
            myLib.map = map;
            myLib.options = options
        }

        return myLib;
    }

    if(typeof (window.testLib) === 'undefined'){
        window.testLib = myLibrary();
    }

})(window, $);
```

**NOTE**

As Alex Wayne pointed out if there is no other use for the local map and options variables you can remove their local references to make your code cleaner like so

```
(function(window, $){
    'use strict';

    function myLibrary(){
        var myLib = {};

        //_options =  {'map':ol.map, 'geojson': testdata}
        myLib.init = function init(_options){
            myLib.map = _options.map;
            myLib.options = _options
        }

        return myLib;
    }

    if(typeof (window.testLib) === 'undefined'){
        window.testLib = myLibrary();
    }

})(window, $);
```

Comment: But then there is no point to have those variables be internal and private.

Comment: @AlexWayne just presented a way that works with the minimum changes. The OP can explain if there is any other use of those variables

Comment: I need the map attribute because I will have to do some action on it, same things for options, I will need to access to the data in the options

Comment: @AlexWayne   and eltonkamami     indeed I dont need the  variables  'map'   and 'options'   to be private.  I could just  use  'myLib.map'  myLib.options.    But by making the asignment inside the anonymous function,  it is difficult to see the myLib had some attributes, a person had to dig into the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/nhgdtf0v/), you should have set the map and options using `this` so the will be part of the object and not only `private members`.

```
(function(window, $){
    'use strict';


    function myLibrary(){
        var myLib = {};
        var options= {};
        var map;

        //_options =  {'map':ol.map, 'geojson': testdata}
        myLib.init = function init(_options){
            this.options = _options;

            this.map = _options.map;
            console.log("Initializing  ...");
            console.log("map : "+ map);
            console.log("options : "+ options);
        }

        myLib.map = map;
        myLib.options = options;

        return myLib;
    }

    if(typeof (window.testLib) === 'undefined'){
        window.testLib = myLibrary();
    }


})(window, $);
```